# How to detect if the current Go process is running in a headless (non-GUI) environment?

Tags: go, headless

I have a Go program which wants to install a trayicon. In case the process is headless, that is, it will not be able to create a graphical user interface, the Go program still makes sense and shall run, but obviously it shall not install the trayicon.

What is the way in Go how to detect whether the current Go process is headless?

Currently, I use the following code:

```
func isHeadless() bool {
    _, display := os.LookupEnv("DISPLAY")
    return !(runtime.GOOS == "windows" || display)
}
```

This code works just fine on a "normal" Windows, Linux, or Mac OS X, and I bet it will also run just fine on FreeBSD, NetBSD, Dragonfly and many others.

Still, that code obviously has a lot of problems:

- It assumes that Windows is never headless (wrong, what if the process was started without a user logged in, and also, there's Windows 10 IoT Core which can be configured to headless https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/headlessmode)
- It doesn't support Android (of which there also is a headless version for IoT).
- It assumes that everything non-Windows has an X-Server and thus a DISPLAY environment variable (wrong, for example, Android)

So, what is the correct way in Go to detect whether the current process is headless / running in a headless environment?

I'm not looking for workarounds, like adding a `--headless` command line switch to my program. Because, I already *have* that anyway for users who have heads but want the program to behave as if it were headless.

In some other programming environments, such capabilities exist. For example, Java has `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()`, and I'm looking for a similar capability in Go.

Some people have suggested to simply try creating the UI, and catch the error. This does not work, at least not with the library that I use. I use `github.com/getlantern/systray`. When `systray.Run()` cannot create the UI, the process dies. My code to setup the system tray looks like this:

```
func setupSystray() { // called from main()
    go func() {
        systray.Run(onReady, nil)
    }()
}

func onReady() {
    systray.SetTitle("foo")
    // ...
}
```

When I run this code on Linux with `DISPLAY` unset, the output is as following:

```
$ ./myapp-linux-amd64
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(myapp-linux-amd64:5783): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:42:37.914: cannot open display: 
$ echo $?
1
```

It could be argued that this is a flaw in the library (and I have created a ticket on the library https://github.com/getlantern/systray/issues/71), but nonetheless some other APIs and environments provide a function `isHeadless()`, and I'm looking for an equivalent in Golang.

Comment: This *might* be possible, but would be incredibly difficult and offer little value. To determine if a machine is "headless" (i.e. with no attached display) would require querying the attached devices, which would require platform-specific system calls for every supported OS, and elevated privileges.

Comment: @Flimzy I define "headless" as the environment being unable or justifiedly unwilling to provide the capability for a graphical user interface for the process. For example, Java has an API call `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()` for that purpose.

Comment: @Adrian Indeed it would require platform-specific code, but I doubt whether it would require elevated privileges. For systems on which the presence of an X server can be assumed for headed systems, such as BSD, Darwin, and Linux, the check of the `DISPLAY` environment variable probably is sufficient. Java provides an `isHeadless()` function, and it operates just fine without elevated privileges.

Comment: The presence of an X server is orthogonal to operating headless. An X server can run on a headless machine for the purpose of allowing GUI remote access.

Comment: @Adrian If an X server is running, for example, in the form of Xvnc, and accessible by the process, the environment is headed. What exactly is all this arguing about? Headed / Headless are set and clear terms, in Java, CI/CD, Selenium, nobody is confused about that, what's going on here?

Comment: You seem to be confused about these terms. A headless machine is one *without an attached display*, regardless of whether X is running. The "head" is the display, not the GUI software. See, for example, the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_computer: "One can also use systems such as X Window System and VNC combined with virtual display drivers - this setup allows remote connections to headless machines through ordinary graphical user interfaces, often running over network protocols like TCP/IP." or here: https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/headless-server

Comment: @Adrian Uhm, where am I talking about a headless machine? I'm not confused about anything. I'm interested whether the process is headless. Whether the machine is headless is irrelevant for displaying a tray icon. I think you must have misread "headed" as "headless" in my previous comment. I want to know whether the App can create a GUI, and I'm never talking of whether a monitor is attached or not, that's irrelevant for being headless from a software perspective, because of what exactly you describe, remote access. I don't care whether access was local or remote.

Comment: The title of your question is "How to detect if the current Go process is running in a headless environment?". Perhaps you could rephrase the question in terms of whether there is a GUI available rather than whether it is running headless, because headless is a hardware concept which seems to be irrelevant to your needs based on your comments.

Comment: @Adrian headless is not a hardware concept. Headless machine is a hardware concept. The term headless itself is a much broader term. There also is headless software https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_software. And headless testing with Selenium/Webdriver. Whether `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()` returns `true` or `false` is a software question, not a hardware question. On Linux and Solaris, `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()` returns `true` exactly if `DISPLAY` is set and non-empty. And I wouldn't claim that Java has a misnomer in its API, not in this instance.

Comment: @ChristianHujer: Your definition is problematic, because it includes motivation. It's impossible, programatically, to determine if a machine is "justified" in not providing a GUI.

Comment: You should report this as an issue to the getlantern/systray authors. They could make a trivial change to cause Run() to return an error instead of exiting. In particular they need to call gtk_init_check() instead of gtk_init() and return an error if it fails.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I already did that.

Comment: No, I'm not imposing anything. I'm conforming your title to match your explained desires. You are, of course, free to revert helpful edits, though. But it won't help you get better answers.

Comment: I give up. I even wanted to delete this question, but StackOverflow doesn't let me. I find the reaction to Go questions on StackOverflow a very unpleasant experience. I haven't experienced such unpleasentness and arrogance ("I know better what headless means than you, and I don't care how Sun, Oracle, Java and others define headless" - you didn't say that, but that's your attitude) anywhere else on StackOverflow. I retreat. I give up. I will not ask Go questions again on StackOverflow.

Comment: The problem with "headless" is it has multiple, conflicting meanings. It can mean hardware with no monitor attached, it can mean a process with no console attached (typical Unix definition)--it can mean a process or OS with no GUI capabilities (seems to be roughly what you're talking about). My edit was to clarify your question. The fact that you "disagree" with that is, from my perspective, absurd. What is there to disagree with? Do you disagree that "headless" is ambiguous? Maybe you disagree with _how_ I interpreted the rest of your question (non-GUI)?

Comment: Nobody said they know better than you what headless means.  We simply asked _what do you mean_?  And you gave an answer. That answer seems reasonable. What's not reasonable is refusing clarifying edits to your question.

Comment: There's no reason to "give up".  The Go community is a bit special in some ways (not just on SO). But then so is every other programming community. The fact that Go is still relatively new probably means it's also more likely to be comprised of early adopters, and other high-motivation, highly-technical people. That will be progressively less true over time.  But the problem with _this question_ has exactly nothing to do with Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the perceived absence of a library/solution for this, I've created one myself. https://github.com/christianhujer/isheadless

Example Usage:

```
package main

import (
    . "fmt"
    . "github.com/christianhujer/isheadless"
    . "os"
)

func main() {
    headless := IsHeadless()
    Fprintf(Stderr, "%s: info: headless: %v\n", Args[0], headless)
    Exit(map[bool]int{true: 0, false: 1}[headless])
}
```

Example runs:

```
$ ./isheadless ; echo $?
./isheadless: info: headless: false
1
$ DISPLAY= ./isheadless ; echo $?
./isheadless: info: headless: true
0
```

Comment: Under Windows there is the following magic trick: https://gist.github.com/yougg/213250cc04a52e2b853590b06f49d865

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be attacking this problem from a wrong angle.

Detecting *reliably* that your program really sees a headless machine is, IMO, rather futile for a number of reasons.

Hence I think I'd adopt an approach usually sported in, say, working with filesystems:

1. Try to perform an operation.
2. If it fails, collect the error.
3. Analyze the error and act accordingly.

That is, just try to explicitly initialize the client (yours) side of whatever works with the GUI stack in your code, trap any possible error and analyze it. If it says it failed to initialize the subsystem, then just raise a relevant flag and proceed.

Comment: BTW, Christian, could you shed a bit more light for me on how do you define a headless Windows machine? I thought that there any non-service application has access to _some_ desktop session anyway (I mean, even on "core" Server flavors). Am I wrong?

Comment: Indeed even what one would call a headless Windows machine (one with no display attached) still runs a GUI accessible by RDP.

Comment: @kostix see for example Windows 10 IoT Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/headlessmode There is such a thing as headless Windows, officially.

Comment: @kostix Please clarify why you think that would be rather futile. Java even provides an API call for that, `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()`.

Comment: @kostix Also please note that I'm not interested in knowing whether the machine is headless. If headless machine or headless hardware is mentioned anywhere in my question, please point it out and I'll fix it. I'm interested whether the process is running in a headless environment. On X, if `DISPLAY` is set, it's headed (although might be misconfigured), if `DISPLAY` is unset, it's headless. Where that X is running, via `ssh -X` / `ssh -Y`, or Xvnc, or whatever, plays no role for being headed.

Comment: @kostix However, I think my question title might have left doubts about that. I hope I fixed that now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer to the question *precisely as it was stated*
is to just look at what Java does in its `isHeadless()`.

[Here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/master/file/be620a591379/src/java.desktop/share/classes/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.java#l166) is what OpenJDK 10 does.

I cannot copy the code as it would supposedly breach its license,
but in essense, the breakdown is as follows:

1. Get system property "java.awt.headless"; use it, if found.
2. Get system property "javaplugin.version"; if it exists,
   the session is not headless. Use this value.
3. Get system property "os.name". If it literally contains
   the substring "OS X" and the system property "awt.toolkit"
   equals the string "sun.awt.HToolkit", the session is not headless.
   Use this value.
4. Check whether the system property "os.name"
   equals one of "Linux", "SunOS", "FreeBSD", "NetBSD", "OpenBSD"
   or "AIX", and if so, try to find an environment variable "DISPLAY";
   if it's absent, the session is headless.

As you can see, in reality the check is pretty lame
and I fail to see any special treatment of Windows.

Still, this answers your question precisely.